# The member variable of a lvalue object is rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

I found that the member variable of a lvalue object is recognized as rvalue, I am wondering why. Here is my example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct CAT
{
    CAT(){}
    int age_;
};


void f(int&& )
{
    cout<<"f(int&&)"<<endl;
}

void f(int &)
{

    cout<<"f(int&)"<<endl;
}


template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    f(std::forward<int>(t.age_));
}


int main()
{
    CAT c;  
    foo(c);            //c is lvalue
    foo(std::move(c)); //move(c) is rvalue
}
```

output:

```
f(int&&)
f(int&&)
```

I have test it using clang3.6 and gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: That's not how `std::forward` is meant to be used...

Comment: You probably meant `f(std::forward<T>(t).age_);`.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't prove anything about `c`. It proves a thing about `std::forward<int>(t.age_)` which is, of course, an rvalue expression.

You should be forwarding `t` (not `t.age_`) as the entire point is to use the universal reference to `T`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    f(std::forward<T>(t).age_);
}
```

[Now it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d8c241e09f82585):

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
> f(int&)
> f(int&&)
> ```

Comment: Forward<int&>(t) is still nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit std::forward<int>(t.age_) should be lvalue not rvalue

Comment: @camino: That's not true, though `std::forward<int&>(t.age_)` is an lvalue expression.